# Add Remove Class on Scroll ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am stuck in this problem. I want to add/remove the class on a header element on scroll, but somehow I can not manage it.

I tried to mount and unmount (found few solutions here on Stack) but does not work in my case. Simply because in most of those cases the code relates to component but I have a little bit different set-up.

Here the full code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-villani-lduor?fontsize=14

I want to add the new class on `store_details_header`

```
const handleChangeIndex = index => {
    setValue(index);
  };

  if (!selectedStore) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div className="store-details">
      <div className="store-details__header" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${selectedStore.headerBackgroundImgUrl})` }}>
        <img className="store-details__header__exit" src={exit} alt="exit" onClick={backToNearYou} />
        <img className="store-details__header__logo" src={selectedStore.headerLogoUrl} alt="logo" />
      </div>
      <div className="store-details__content" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${selectedStore.contentBackgroundImgUrl})` }}>
        <div>
          <AppBar className={props.classes.root} position="static" color="default">
            <Tabs value={value} classes={{ indicator: props.classes.indicator }} onChange={setSelectedNavigationItem} variant="fullWidth">
              <StyledTab label="Products" />
              <StyledTab label="Items" />
            </Tabs>
          </AppBar>
          <SwipeableViews axis={'x'} index={value} onChangeIndex={handleChangeIndex}>
            <TabContainer>
              {' '}
              <div className="store-details__content__items">{renderSliderItems()}</div>
            </TabContainer>
            <TabContainer>
              {' '}
              <div className="store-details__content__items">{renderSliderItems()}</div>
            </TabContainer>
          </SwipeableViews>
        </div>
      </div>
      {guestMode && renderGuestModeBox()}
      {selectedStore.loyaltyCard && renderLoyaltyCard()}
    </div>
  );
};

  const handleChangeIndex = index => {
    setValue(index);
  };

  if (!selectedStore) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div className="store-details">
      <div className="store-details__header" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${selectedStore.headerBackgroundImgUrl})` }}>
        <img className="store-details__header__exit" src={exit} alt="exit" onClick={backToNearYou} />
        <img className="store-details__header__logo" src={selectedStore.headerLogoUrl} alt="logo" />
      </div>
      <div className="store-details__content" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${selectedStore.contentBackgroundImgUrl})` }}>
        <div>
          <AppBar className={props.classes.root} position="static" color="default">
            <Tabs value={value} classes={{ indicator: props.classes.indicator }} onChange={setSelectedNavigationItem} variant="fullWidth">
              <StyledTab label="Products" />
              <StyledTab label="Items" />
            </Tabs>
          </AppBar>
          <SwipeableViews axis={'x'} index={value} onChangeIndex={handleChangeIndex}>
            <TabContainer>
              {' '}
              <div className="store-details__content__items">{renderSliderItems()}</div>
            </TabContainer>
            <TabContainer>
              {' '}
              <div className="store-details__content__items">{renderSliderItems()}</div>
            </TabContainer>
          </SwipeableViews>
        </div>
      </div>
      {guestMode && renderGuestModeBox()}
      {selectedStore.loyaltyCard && renderLoyaltyCard()}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I think you forgot to save your sandbox

Comment: Your codesandbox is giving error `withStyles is not defined`. Please fix it.

Comment: @MukeshPrajapati I can not post entire code it's under NDA therefore only this part to give you a glimpe where my problem occurs. It should be enough for someone to write how to add/remove class on scroll.